# Bitcoin Wallet - An unconfirmed transaction that was later resent and confirmed still shows up on total

Tags: wallet

I use the wallet Bitcoin Wallet from the Google Play store, and recently received a transaction for some BTC. However, this transaction is really a resend of an earlier transaction for the exact same amount that was rejected.

Despite this, the earlier transaction (showing up as unconfirmed in the wallet) is still adding to my shown total, and is making my total amount inaccurate. Is there a way to delete the transaction from my history so that it does not show up on the total?